# How to append all records of one Sharepoint List to another list in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, powerapps

I am developing a questionnaire application with PowerApps that is for a group of employees who are supposed to answer 150 questions.

I created one SharePoint list to store the Employee info, Another list to store the 150 questions, and a third list to store the connection between the employee ID, Question ID and the answers.

What I'd like to  do is , as soon as a new employee adds their name in the employee list, 150 rows adds to the responses list with employee ID and question ID. So the employee can go and edit the rows by answering the questions.

How can I dynamically append those 150 questions to the answers list?

Comment: In your powerautomate set the trigger as `When an item is created` and then just do `Get All Items` for the questions list and then for each item using `Apply to each` create a new row in your required list (using `Create new Item`).